# Angular: ng-options add custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I want to create a select tag with 'selected' value. I am doing this with **ng-repeat** since I cannot add a custom directive to **ng-options**. This is the code.

```
    <select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-model="selectedCity">
        <option ng-repeat="city in allCities" value="{{city.id}}" after-render-cities>{{city.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

This adds an extra option with value =?string:1? which I searched a lot. Since **ng-options** solves this issue, I however have to add the directive **after-render-cities** for each option. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: *"I however have to add the directive after-render-cities for each option"*. Why, what does after-render-cities do?

Comment: Its an android cordova app. I hide the splashscreen after data is rendered in html.

Comment: You can still hide it, you don't need this directive.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="city.id as city.name for city in allCities">
</select>
```

for selection of first value, write following code in your controller

```
$scope.selectedCity = $scope.allCities[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-init for solve value =?string:1?

```
<select class="ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-model="selectedCity" ng-init='selectedCity=allCities[0].id'>
    <option ng-repeat="city in allCities" value="{{city.id}}" after-render-cities>{{city.name}}</option>
</select>
```

another choice you can use ng-selected [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn1Lwm7y/)

```
 <option ng-repeat="(key,city) in allCities" ng-selected='key==0' value="{{city.id}}" after-render-cities>{{city.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: ng-init worked. But I had to remove ng-model. With ng-model it does not work.

Comment: why you have remove ng-model?

Comment: Dont know. It doesn't work with ng-model though. Now I am trying to bind the value with ng-model on 'change' event

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `directive`, using `select` and `ng-options`.

**Snippet**:

*JS:*

```
template: "<select ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in list' ng-model='data'></select>",
```

*HTML:*

```
<div select-option list="list" ng-model='data'></div>
```

Refer to the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/8s7novgo/).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

**Java Script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Cities = [
         { Id: 1, Name: "New York" },
         { Id: 2, Name: "Colombo" },
         { Id: 3, Name: "Real Madrid" },
         { Id: 4, Name: "Bostan" },
         { Id: 5, Name: "Birmingham" }
      ];
    $scope.City= 3;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select ng-options="C.Id as C.Name for C in Cities" ng-model="City"></select>
```

[Read This Blog, it has everything explained.](http://easycodestuff.blogspot.com/2015/12/binding-data-to-drop-down-in-html-with.html)